# How to send file using tibco ems

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, businessworks, tibco-business-works

I have one requirement in my TIBCO project in which I have to send one file of csv type using TIBCO Queue Sender activity .
So, Can anybody help me in this ?
Apart from this let me know all the possible ways of sending file using TIBCO ems ?
Thanks

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Hi Cliff , Okay could you please let me know how can we send a file using tibco ems queue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you mention EMS, you haven't given much information about what product and what version you're using to implement this solution. Because of the specific terminology you've used, I'm going to assume you're referring to BusinessWorks and are using the TIBCO Designer.

To do what you're describing in BW, you'll want to add a "Read File" activity (from the File Palette) to your BW Process. Configure/map this activity's input with the input CSV filename/path, and map the activity's output bytes/text to the input body of a JMS Send Message activity (name may vary by version of BusinessWorks, 5.x vs 6.x). Enter the appropriate destination name, and select the correct JMS Configuration resource.

That's about it!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, TIBCO EMS is not a file transferring solution but a messaging solution.  If you still want to send the file(data) using EMS you can use a ReadFile activity and provide output of fileContent and input to body of send EMS queue message activity. But in this will you will loose the file properties.